# How to get the days within a range of two dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I have the **calendar** table with all the dates of the month of December 2021 (I will only exemplify some dates within the table, but it is understood that it actually contains all the days of said month):

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-01 |
| 02 | 2021-12-02 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 |

I have the **users** table:

| ID | name | num_employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Andrew | 101 |
| 02 | Mary | 102 |

I have the table **assistances**

| ID | date | num_employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-03 | 101 |
| 02 | 2021-12-04 | 101 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 | 102 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 | 102 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 | 101 |
| 06 | 2021-12-06 | 102 |

I have a query to display the employee number, their name, the days they attended and the days they were absent:

```
SELECT u.num_employee,
       u.name,
       a.date AS attendances,
        (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM calendar
           WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
           AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date),a.date)) as faults FROM users u
JOIN (SELECT num_employee,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM attendances
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      GROUP BY num_employee) a ON a.num_employee = u.num_employee
```

With the above query, I get this:

| num_employee | name | attendances | faults |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrew | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10... |
| 102 | Mary | 3,4,6 | 1,2,5,7,8,9,10... |

Now, the point is that in addition to the **attendances** table, I have to consider another table called **vacations**. The structure of this table is as follows:

| id | initial_date | final_date | num_employee |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-07 | 2021-12-09 | 101 |
| 02 | 2021-12-07 | 2021-12-09 | 102 |

And taking this table into consideration, the days within the ranges that are handled as vacations should stop appearing in the "faults" column. The result should be the following:

| num_employee | name | attendances | faults |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrew | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,6,10... |
| 102 | Mary | 3,4,6 | 1,2,5,10... |

How can I adapt my query to get the above?

The query in question cannot be adapted to use CTE given the version of MariaDB I am using. I am working on phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MySQL and MariaDB are bad with sequences, it is good that you have a calendar table to run against.

So another subquery that retrieves the dates of the vacation is needed.

I used a `GROUP BY` in the subselect as there could be more than 1 vacation period in a month.

> ```
> SELECT u.num_employee,
>        u.name,
>        a.date AS attendances,
>         (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM calendar
>            WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
>            AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date),a.date)
>            AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date),vac.vac_days)) as faults 
> FROM users u
> LEFT JOIN  (SELECT num_employee,
>       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM attendances
>       WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
>       GROUP BY num_employee) a ON a.num_employee = u.num_employee
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT v.`num_employee`, GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(c.`date`)) vac_days
> FROM vacations v INNER JOIN calendar c ON c.`date` BETWEEN v.`initial_date` AND `final_date`
> AND c. date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
> GROUP BY v.`num_employee`) vac ON vac.`num_employee` = u.num_employee
> ```
>
> ```
> num_employee | name   | attendances | faults     
> -----------: | :----- | :---------- | :----------
>          101 | Andrew | 3,4,5       | 1,2,6,10,11
>          102 | Mary   | 3,4,6       | 1,2,5,10,11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0268366119334f3c5b2573bdb01881a7)*

FIND_IN_SET needs a string and doesn't work with `NULL`, so you need to check for NULL Values and replace them

> ```
> SELECT u.num_employee,
>        u.name,
>        a.date AS attendances,
>         (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM calendar
>            WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
>            AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date),IFNULL(a.date,''))
>            AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date),IFNULL(vac.vac_days,''))
>            ) as faults 
> FROM users u
> LEFT JOIN  (SELECT num_employee,
>       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM attendances
>       WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
>       GROUP BY num_employee) a ON a.num_employee = u.num_employee
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT v.`num_employee`, GROUP_CONCAT(DAY(c.`date`)) vac_days
> FROM vacations v INNER JOIN calendar c ON c.`date` BETWEEN v.`initial_date` AND `final_date`
> AND c. date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
> GROUP BY v.`num_employee`) vac ON vac.`num_employee` = u.num_employee
> ```
>
> ```
> num_employee | name   | attendances | faults           
> -----------: | :----- | :---------- | :----------------
>          101 | Andrew | 3,4,5       | 1,2,6,10,11      
>          102 | Mary   | 3,4,6       | 1,2,5,7,8,9,10,11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e74fae07caa6e72ca05ed7e262a3107c)*

Comment: Thanks for your help! But it only shows people with vacations; people who are not in the vacations table but are in the attendance table are not shown

Comment: you need tp use  `LEFT JOIN` insetad of an `INNER JOIN` see example

Comment: Thanks again for your help, it worked. One last question: You know why the last day of the month (2021-12-31) it's on the "faults" column even if the date appears on the "attendances" table?

Comment: @AndreaDuran are you sure ? see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1cc4666b5f9629d9b9c846c66b08b8e4 manipulate the dbfiddle to´till you get your problem

Comment: @AndreaDuran is there a problem?

Comment: I previously reviewed your response and thought that what was expected was obtained, but upon reviewing it carefully I realized that although all employees are now listed, employees who do not have vacations, but do have absences, appear as NULL in the column of faults. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a59c3bbe8dad87330afc3cd1aba68c8e

Comment: FIND_IN_SET needs a string and doesn't workwoth NULL, so you need to check foor NULL Values
  see the changed answer